# tightly couple properties of 2 interfaces using generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't know if this is even possible using typescript, but want to be sure to learn something new today. :)

The idea is to create a simple component in React using Typescript.

The usage of the component should look something similar to this one:

```
<Grid gridTemplateAreas="'item1 item2' 'item3 item3'">
  <Grid.Item gridArea="item1">1st item of grid</Grid.Item>
  <Grid.Item gridArea="item2">2nd item of grid</Grid.Item>
  <Grid.Item gridArea="item3">3rd item of grid</Grid.Item>
</Grid>
```

Now, when creating these components, I want to make their props typesafe. But I am not sure, what types should I use for the props:

```
interface GridProps {
  gridTemplateAreas: ???;
}

interface GridItemProps<T extends string> {
  gridArea: T; // I guess this should be something similar
}
```

Can someone give me a start on how to define the types, so that gridTemplateAreas and gridArea properties are tightly coupled for type safety?

Comment: I think a good start to learn something new is right there: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Comment: @indyteo thanks for the link to template literal types, I will check it out and will try to apply it in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, but here is an alternative API you could use:

```
<Grid gridTemplateAreas="'item1 item2' 'item3 item3'" items={[
    { gridArea: "item1", element: <>1st item of grid</> },
    { gridArea: "item2", element: <>2nd item of grid</> },
    { gridArea: "item3", element: <>3rd item of grid</> },
]} />
```

Your Grid component would need to be generic:

```
function Grid<Template extends string>(props: GridProps<Template>) {
```

Here's the GridProps type:

```
interface GridProps<Template extends string> {
    gridTemplateAreas: Template;
    items: { gridArea: AreasFromTemplate<Template>; element: React.ReactNode }[];
}
```

The difficult thing about this is that we'd have to essentially parse the grid template areas at compile time and then use the parsed cells for the type of the grid areas.

```
type Whitespace = " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\f" | "\v" | "\r";

type TrimStart<S extends string> = S extends `${Whitespace}${infer Rest}` ? TrimStart<Rest> : S;
type TrimEnd<S extends string> = S extends `${infer Rest}${Whitespace}` ? TrimEnd<Rest> : S;
type Trim<S extends string> = TrimStart<TrimEnd<S>>;

type AreasFromRow<Row extends string> = Row extends `${infer Cell} ${infer Rest}` ? Cell | AreasFromRow<Trim<Rest>> : Row;
type AreasFromTemplate<Template extends string> = Template extends `"${infer Row}"${infer Rest}` | `'${infer Row}'${infer Rest}` ? AreasFromRow<Row> | AreasFromTemplate<Trim<Rest>> : never;
```

so that:

```
type X = AreasFromTemplate<"'item1 item2' 'item3 item3'">; // "item1" | "item2" | "item3"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgHEpgATABRzAGcAPABUk4ADYo6cJAA861Dnzh8Y7agHMAfHADe5OAbjr2HEeMlIAgkRR8AXHDNgJdCobjA6Ie7qMnrqA4BtgBiOCBOLkjCos4WmqTSYqJItA7I6DAAdBkYAHIQHMwAvgDaALoUxZSYAK7UGMAQ1KwmMeZSsvKKyqo0WgAUYLw+bJw8EPztcXSaAJS+RDC1UC0CHMAAbpoCAPQb23DV5DAAnmDMAOoAFp5IfGBMcAC8BG8APgQAOjD4cJ-4L7UP4Ar6YEHfTYQwFQMiUM4XRzsEAAZRgKFgAhR0jkqR6KjUWhecGxXTxSgABgASHQ3O4PJjFGk0TD0RD3GDFClwAD8SNAaIxMAEyBU2gcKIoCOYQmRAFEFFicd0lAT+tpXqTcQpKczqKyoOyVEzabc6Ay0Egubz+SAFRwRRzxSSpecZcilWSdb1CRrbYLMbLQPasZoEvC3XBgnwwrgEBAAO4ixPK8k+9XE+MJ1Pe6k6FlsgDCSDEYmKcD1BqNnO5fOLpf+UZsMfCWeEHtFMDDcHSiddiOjsYisSi0yiOfxfQ0fsiFgnlPwlbZWeKi-z+uXHOtnwpAHIl4aV-v11XO9a+YPW4nkwntJ9L7hZ3R26BHWLndQkJt6BRyHUGjATQtIWuCQJ+tADAsejuEsKwtAM+juIYAhjBwficE+VjNs8+C7ncIAAIweF4ABMu5wHhXgAMzEaIVG7n8+F8M8OilIhSFITo6EcMEDj4PhBH4AANEkKRpHAAiaARKi0XgECYNxezaMUQnsRxhhccYnC8QQ+EkcJokgKkMAOJJJEKLJcDyYpuzKap6mcdxOn8dRBklmJJkSZoVFQGh+FWQpWkOrZRz2ep5TlrZalzFU5BAA)

Comment: That's an awesome answer. Thank you! I would love to learn the basics of typescript. Can you please suggest some learning path?