# Generic react children type for compound components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `Table` component that accepts `Column` components as children:

```
  <Table data={data}>
    <Column cell={(c) => c.date} header="Date" />
    <Column cell={(c) => c.count} header="Count" />
  </Table>
```

I want to type `Table` and `Column` so that `cell` props infers the type passed to `data`.
This way when I pass

```
const data = [
    {
      date: "12-12-2012",
      count: 12
    }
  ];
```

as `data` that would be fine, but if e.g. count is missing it would error out on the second column.

I tried:

```
type ColumnProps<T> = {
  header: string;
  cell: (data: T) => string;
};

type TableProps<T> = {
  data: T[];
  children: React.ReactElement<ColumnProps<T>>[];
};
```

However this still shows `c` in `cell` as `unknown`

Comment: Not possible, you may have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608356/tightly-couple-properties-of-2-interfaces-using-generics/75608965#75608965) where you pass the columns to the table component as props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous comment is correct – the relationship between components in a TSX hierarchy isn't typed strongly enough to infer the type from the container to the children. There's also the small issue of JSX syntax abuse to define the columns ... I'm not sure how that would work.

The good news though is that you could do something similar by using, say, plain old JS objects rather than JSX to define your columns:

```js
type TableProps<T> = {
  data: T[];
  columns: {
    cell: (data: T) => string;
    header: string;
  }[];
};
...
    <Table
      data={data}
      columns={[
        { header: "Date",  cell: (c) => c.date },
        { header: "Count", cell: (c) => String(c.count) }
      ]}
    />
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-browser-pf6ho2?file=/src/App.tsx)

This happily infers the type in the `cell` callbacks.